# Can iOS display the current audio input device?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, microphone

Is there any way to tell whether an attached external mic is making contact with an iOS device?

I am trying to attach an external microphone (Sennheiser MKE-400) to an iPhone 5. The mic has a 3.5mm jack which fits into the iPhone's headphone port. I know that the port is capable of audio input. However, I also know that there are different formats for 3.5 mm jacks and ports, and that there are adapters available, one of which may be required to make this connection, though I am not sure.

I can make a recording with the mic attached, but from listening to it, it is not clear whether the mic is in use or whether the iPhone is using its own, built-in mic.

Comment: It is using its own built in mic because the 2 pins on the 3.5mm adapter are being used as an output. The third pin on headphones with mics is where the microphone comes into play, so to summarise you need either a 3 pin microphone cable or an adapter like suggested in @admish 's answer

Answer (score 1):

You would need an adapter to make that mic work with an iPhone.  [Such as this one.](http://www.filmtools.com/owle-bubo-iphone-4-mic-adapter.html)